# Woher kommt der Ausdruck "rein gar nichts"?

Tags: meaning

Als Steigerung von *gar nichts* finde ich oft, geschrieben und gesprochen, *rein gar nichts*.

Was ist der Ursprung dieser Formulierung?

Ist es etwa eine französische Wortverdoppelung a la *mit avec*, also das Hinzufügen vom französischen *rien* zu *gar nichts*, gemixt mit einer Eindeutschung a la *mutterseelenallein* (*moi, tout seul, allein*)?

Comment: Während ich die Herkunftserklärung von *mutterseelenallein* auf Wikipedia finden konnte, listet der Duden aber folgendes auf: *zu älter Mutterseele = Menschenseele, Mensch, eigentlich = menschenallein, von allen Menschen verlassen*

Comment: Ich hatte die Erklaerung aus der Sendung Karambolage von arte.

Comment: Vielleicht hat die Person, die den Wikipedia Artikel geschrieben hat, die gleiche Sendung gesehen? :-D

Answer (score 3):

"Rein" bedeutet ja in etwa "sauber", "frei von allem", "nur das und nichts anderes". Somit könnte "rein gar nichts" eine kurze Form von "gar nichts und nichts anderes als gar nichts" sein, was einfach das "nichts" nochmal zweimal betont. Klingt philosophisch?

Answer (score 2):

Ich glaube, dass "rein" hier eine Verkürzung von "reinweg" ist (u.a. Synonym für "schlicht" oder "schlicht und einfach") und mit "rien" nichts zu tun hat.